# Are exceptions propagated through component bindings?

Tags: mule

Using the Mule config and Java code below, I cannot get Mule to propagate exceptions through the component binding. How can I get exceptions thrown on the remote service to propagate to the calling component? Mule EE 3.2.2

Thanks

**The Mule config**

```
<mule ...>
    <flow name="Test">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="Test" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <component class="foo.Component">
        <binding interface="foo.Interface" method="bar">
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="Interface.bar"
                    exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        </binding>
        </component>
    </flow>

    <flow name="Interface.bar">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="Interface.bar" 
            exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <scripting:component>
            <scripting:script engine="groovy">
                throw new Exception();
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**The Java Code**

Component.java

```
package foo;

public class Component {

    private Interface theInterface;

    public void foo(final String unused) throws Exception {
        theInterface.bar();
    }

    public void set(final Interface anInterface) {
        theInterface = anInterface;
    }

}
```

Interface.java

```
package foo;

public interface Interface {

    String bar() throws Exception;

}
```

**The driver**

```
package foo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.client.MuleClient;
import org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest extends FunctionalTestCase {

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void willItThrowException() throws MuleException {
        final MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
        client.send("vm://Test", "", null, RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "app/mule-config.xml";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are not propagated as "thrown exceptions" through message exchanges but as an exception payload on the in-flight message.

So the response of calling `vm://Interface.bar` should be a message that has an exception payload set with the exception you've thrown. Because binding binds the main payload to the interface, there's no way to access it from the component.

One option would be to add a response transformer in the `Interface.bar` flow that would copy the exception payload (if any) to the main payload and allow bar() to return Object (sometimes it would be a String, sometimes an Exception). Or stay with String and define a convention for returned errors as String.